# <ui:param and caching

Tags: jsf-2, jstl, facelets

I have the following thing:

```
<ui:param name="randomVideo" value="#{bean.randomVideo}" />
<a href="#{randomVideo.link}">#{randomVideo.text}</a&></pre>
```

Because `<ui:param>` does not cache the variable, `Bean.getRandomVideo()` is called twice, and the worst part is that the `.text` and `.link` are from different videos. I have already tried `<c:set` and `<f:param`. They both do not set the variable, maybe because I'm with facelets (JSF2).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getters are supposed to be real getters, not containing any logic. So:

- make your `bean` `@RequestScoped`
- initialize the `randomVideo` field in `@PostConstruct`
- let the getter only retrieve the `randomVideo` field of the bean.

Comment: Actually, I had to move my logic to a new bean, but if we disregard the extra code this solution was better than mine - put the random video in the request and check whether there was anything in the request in the getter)